# Audio Microphone Live Streaming in Android

Tags: android, live-streaming

I am new in live streaming. I have a problem to create live streaming of recording file. I can upload the audio file to server and play from url using media player but i dont want this i want as i speak it broadcast to all and when i finish my speech then it stops broadcasting. Is it feasible or not. If feasible then how?

Can i do this with Amazon CloudFront?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge you can use [Spydroid](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)

it is basically for video streaming but you can use it for audio streaming as well and then you have to alter its code for audio streaming..
seccondly you will need some media server i will prefer you to use Red5 media server as it is opensource [Red 5](http://code.google.com/p/red5/)

red5 supports audio and video streaming both but you have to  study it little bit

Comment: Thanks for answer. Let me check the SpyDroid.

Comment: it will show u nothing more than guiding you RTSP address. you have to dive in its code and it is not a rocket science which you cant understand :) there is a class AMRPacketizer which is of your need